# 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user. .net core yandex mail

Tags: c#, .net-core

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.com", 587);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("site@example.com", "password");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
```

can you help me please ?

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SmtpException: Mailbox name not allowed. The server response was: 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.

Comment: This question isn't related to using the Visual Studio application, nor is it related to ASP.NET Core, so I've removed those tags for you.

Comment: this project .net core

Comment: Yes, but being ASP or not isn't relevant to your question (you certainly haven't shown any evidence that it affects your code above).

Comment: I understood thank you

Comment: By the way, from the error message, it seems like your from address isn't owned by site@example.com. Presumably this is to stop people from using Yandex's mail servers for phishing by faking other people's email addresses, etc.

Comment: No, I wrote as an example

Comment: a different domain name

Comment: You can't be using the same e-mail address for FROM and for login though, is my point. That's what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

The yandex mail server requests that the **sending e-mail address** be the same as the **credential** e-mail address. You have not included the full code structure here, if you edit it as below, the problem will be solved.

The sender information and the credential information must be the same (In the example below, the `userName` field)

```
string userName = "name@sitedomain.com";  
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();    
msg.From = new MailAddress(userName, "Name to appear on sender");
```

The e-mail addresses I specified with this `userName` must be the same.

```
NetworkCredential AccountInfo = new NetworkCredential(userName, "pasword here");
```